# php remove first parameters from url path

Tags: php

I have multilingual system and need to remove short default locale prefix from url. I need to check if session get prefix :

```
if(Session::get('prefix')) {
    $url = urldecode(http_build_query($_GET, '', '&'));
} else {
    $url = ''; //This Line
}

echo $url;
//output is: url=fa/account/login
```

Now in action ($url) I see this output:

```
en/
en/account/login
en/account/dashboard
```

Now I need to remove `en` from url path if not detect session prefix like this.

```
account/login
account/dashboard
```

what is best method?!

Comment: You need to add language code in session and use `$_SESSION['language_code']` directly in link codes

Comment: @AlivetoDie: Sure but i need to this url path for back redirect to this.ie: for default language without prefix and another language with prefix. note: i remove default language from url.

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://3v4l.org/CGBVh

Comment: @Thefourthbird: I have this: url=fa/account/login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an array of all your languages. Then you could use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and use a forward slash as the delimiter.

Check if the first item is in the array with languages. If it is, remove the first item from the `$parts` using for example [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) and then reassemble the string again using implode.

```
$langs = ["en", "fa"];
$string = "fa/account/login";
$parts = explode('/', $string);

if (in_array($parts[0], $langs)) {
    array_shift($parts);
}
echo implode('/', $parts) . PHP_EOL; //account/login
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/uKRbA)

Comment: This way is true and work. But I have problem If my url = `en/news/list?page=2&sort=desc` this way not work.

Comment: @harmonytalk What is the result that you get that is not working for you? Did you test it like this? https://3v4l.org/DJEVd

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array in config/app.php  with all languages your application implement . 
For example you can add this line to your config/app.php

```
$languages  = ['en','fa'];
```

and now your can change your code like this :

```
$url = urldecode(http_build_query($_GET, '', '&'));
if(Session::get('prefix') == null) 
    $url = preg_replace("/^".implode(Config::get("app.languages"),"|")."\//",'',$url);
```